# R default output uses pager?

Tags: r

I am working with large data matrices and most of the time I do have to look through all the data in a particular column (for PCA).

I've grown to love `> page(bigmatrix, method="print")`. However, it's troublesome for me because I have to type that every time on the console. Is it possible for me to tell R to wrap all console outputs to use `page` by default?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easist option would be to write a function to do this and put it in your startup `.Rprofile.` Then you could use it easily with something like `p(bigmatrix)`.

I tested it by putting the following at the end of my .Rprofile file (located in the home directory - in Windows that is the Documents directory associated with your user name). It worked fine.

```
p <- function (x){
    page(x, method = "print")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. This is a pretty good idea, though I would prefer having this automatically done.

Comment: Modifying the default behavior might break something though, and you will lose it every time you upgrade. I think this is the only "clean" way to do it, but maybe someone will have another idea.